# Volumetric shows in render results but not after I save the image

Tags: rendering

I have a scene where a volumetric cube shows up in the viewport and rendered view, but if I try to save it to a png, the volumetric disappears. I've tried exporting to every type of image file. I've also tried disabling compositing and the results remain the same. Saving the image to png affects the object only if it's a volumetric. If the object is a diffused material, it works just fine.

The project was made and most recently saved in 3.0.1, but this problem is common across all versions to include pre 2.79.

Rendered result AFTER saving it to PNG

[image]

Render result before saving it to PNG

[image]

Here's a link to the .blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/80f28cd208bb40dba6f71a6b6c98da0d

Comment: Hi, in the future, please use the built in tools that are provided for you to include images inside of your posts rather than using external links. This helps keeps the site more organized, and all information in one place.

Comment: could you plesae share the volumetric object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @Timaroberts is the "image" button on the bar not a built in tool?

Comment: @moonboots Here's the full blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/80f28cd208bb40dba6f71a6b6c98da0d

Comment: @Acaicia the built-in upload tool [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLDnM.png) is what I am referring to. Please read [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) if you are unsure how to use it.

Comment: Hello, I couldn't find where the problem comes from, I hope somenone will